AVPlayerViewController's mute button doesn't work as expected on VisionOS
When I tap on the mute button nothing happens. Besides that, the mute button doesn't get highlighted when the user hovers over it like when I use Safari's Video Player (that looks like AVPlayer).
import SwiftUI
import AVKit

struct ContentView: View {
    @State
    private var player: AVPlayer = .init(
        playerItem: .init(url: .init(string: "https://alternatv.ar/stream/hls/live.m3u8")!)
    )

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            VideoPlayer(
                player: player
            ).onAppear {
                player.play()
            }
        }
    }
}

This is how this code behaves on VisionOS

This is how the Safari's Video Player works

Am I missing something?

You're right, at the moment the Mute button on the volume slider of video player window doesn't work. You can use the following code until Apple engineers fix this option.
import SwiftUI
import AVKit

@main struct VideoPlayerApp : App {
    @State var mediaPlayer = MediaPlayer()
    
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
                .environment(mediaPlayer)
        }
        .windowStyle(.volumetric)
        .defaultSize(width: 1.8, height: 0.9, depth: 0.0, in: .meters)
    }
}


@Observable class MediaPlayer {
    let url = URL(string: "https://alternatv.ar/stream/hls/live.m3u8")!
    let player = AVPlayer()
    var ctrl: AVPlayerViewController? = nil
    
    fileprivate func createController() -> AVPlayerViewController {
        let controller = AVPlayerViewController()
        controller.player = player
        self.ctrl = controller
        
        guard let ctrl else { return .init() }
        return ctrl
    }        
    fileprivate func loadMedia() {
        let item = AVPlayerItem(url: url)
        player.replaceCurrentItem(with: item)
    }
}


struct ContentView : View {
    @Environment(MediaPlayer.self) var mediaPlayer
    @State var isMuted: Bool = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            PlayerViewController()
            
            HStack {
                Spacer()
                Button(isMuted ? "is Muted" : "Unmuted") {
                    isMuted.toggle()
                    mediaPlayer.player.isMuted = isMuted
                }
                .padding(.trailing, 30)
            }
        }
        .onAppear {
            mediaPlayer.loadMedia()
            mediaPlayer.player.volume = 1.5
        }
    }
}


struct PlayerViewController : UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    @Environment(MediaPlayer.self) var mediaPlayer

    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> AVPlayerViewController {
        let pvc = mediaPlayer.createController()
        return pvc
    }
    func updateUIViewController(_ pvc: AVPlayerViewController,
                              context: Context) { }
}


